# ContainerApp deployment fails in Bicep: Failed to provision revision for container app

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

```
 Container App 
resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-04-01-preview'  = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
    }
  properties: {
    environmentId: '/subscriptions/134343-32343-2343-83b5-exy3sd2343/resourceGroups/infra-rg/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/my-env'
    configuration: {
      activeRevisionsMode: 'Single'
      ingress: {
        allowInsecure: false
        external: true
        targetPort: 5173
        }
         registries: [
        {
          server: '${acrName}.azurecr.io'
          identity: 'system'
        } 
      ] 
   
        
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          name: 'my-app'
          command: []
          image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest'
          resources: {
            cpu: json('0.25')
            memory: '.5Gi'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the above bicep template to create a containerApp in Azure. It uses a simple public image. set the containerApp to **system** identity.

When i run this i always get this error(10/10) after about 10 minutes.

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state "code\": \"ContainerAppOperationError\",       \"message\": \"Failed to provision revision for container app 'my-capp'. Error details: Operation expired.
```

This container app is meant to updated later through a pipeline with an image from a private repository in acr. I have given the private repository in the bicep template:

```
 registries: [
        {
          server: '${acrName}.azurecr.io'
          identity: 'system'
        }
```

I notice that when i deploy the bicep template by removing the above section it works and deploys in a minute.

Since i have given a public image, there is no need for the deployment to go into hanging mode when i put the set the registry.  Is there any other way to update the registry for the containerApp through the bicep file?

Can anyone help here?

Comment: If you are trying to pull images from the registries using system assigned identity you need to provide a necessary pull permission to that service principal or user. Then only system identity works. @Coder

Answer (score 0):

After adding especially system assigned identity for the container apps it won't work as expected. It requires ACR pull permissions or other permissions to the service principal or user to pull the image from the registry as detailed in this [blog](https://www.willvelida.com/posts/deploy-container-apps-bicep/#:%7E:text=Creating%20and%20Provisioning%20Azure%20Container%20Apps%20with%20Bicep,our%20Bicep%20Template%20...%203%20Wrapping%20Up%20) by @Will Velida.

> Managed identities can’t be created for our Container Apps.

After a workaround on this, I tried to achieve it by enabling admin user in container registry and using the login to authorize Container App for pulling images from the registry.

```bash
resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2021-12-01-preview' = { 
name: xxxxx
location: location 
sku: { 
   name: 'Basic' 
 } 
 properties: { 
 adminUserEnabled: true 
   } 
 }
```

Or if you will need to work with managed identities, I would suggest you go with the user assigned identity as detailed in the [article](https://azureossd.github.io/2023/01/03/Using-Managed-Identity-and-Bicep-to-pull-images-with-Azure-Container-Apps/) by @Anthony Salemo.

```bash
param  environment  string = ''
param  logAnalyticsWorkspace  string = ''
param  containerapp string = ''
param  acr string = ''
param  acrPullDefinitionId  string = '8311e382-0749-4cb8-b61a-304f252e45ec'
param  userAssignedIdentity  string = 'identiylatest'
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
resource  identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
name: userAssignedIdentity
location: location
}
resource  roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
name: guid(resourceGroup().id,  acr,  'AcrPullTestUserAssigned')
properties: {
principalId: identity.properties.principalId
principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',  acrPullDefinitionId)
  }
}
resource  logAnalyticsWorkspace  'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' = {
name: logAnalyticsWorkspace
location: location
properties: any({
retentionInDays: 30
features: {
searchVersion: 1
}
sku: {
name: 'PerGB2018'
   }
 })
}
resource  appInsights  'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
name: appInsights
location: location
kind: 'web'
properties: {
Application_Type: 'web'
WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
  }
}
resource  appEnvironment  'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-06-01-preview' = {
name: environment
location: location
properties: {
daprAIInstrumentationKey: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
appLogsConfiguration: {
destination: 'log-analytics'
logAnalyticsConfiguration: {
customerId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.properties.customerId
sharedKey: logAnalyticsWorkspace.listKeys().primarySharedKey
   }
  }
 }
}
resource  containerApp  'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-06-01-preview' = {
name: containerapp
location: location
identity: {
type: 'UserAssigned'
userAssignedIdentities: {
'${identity.id}': {}
}
}
properties: {
environmentId: appEnvironment.id
configuration: {
ingress: {
targetPort: xxx
external: true
}
registries: [
{
server: '${acr}.azurecr.io'
identity: identity.id
   }
 ]
}
template: {
containers: [
{
image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest'
name: 'sample-image'
resources: {
cpu: json('0.5')
memory: '1Gi'
   }
 }
]
scale: {
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 1
   }
 }
}
}
```

*Note:* Check the `roledefinitionID` for [ACR Pull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#acrpull) in built-in-roles `MSDoc`.

*Output:*

[image]

[image]

If still the issue persists with the conflict, go to the deployed `container app` -> `Diagnose and solve problems` -> `check availability and performance` for any pull image errors as shown.

[image]